# RestAssured check nested attribut inside an array attribute

Tags: rest, integration-testing, rest-assured, hamcrest

I'm using RestAssured and Hamcrest to code some integration tests.
All was fine until I tried to check nested property.

My Json body is :

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "uid": "927e2362-babb-47cc-8406-d618b0e15b89",
            "owner": "myself"
        },
        {
            "uid": "6d39c473-d0bd-496e-be86-40917aa3af79",
            "owner": "myself"
        }
    ]
}
```

My test code is like that :

```
ValidatableResponse response = request.when().get(path).then();
response.statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

Now I'm trying to add a check that all rows have the property `owner` with the value **myself**

Best I could come up is :

```
response.body("rows.owner", everyItem(is("myself")));
```

However I would much prefer do it using the matcher `Matchers.hasProperty("owner")` or even `HasPropertyWithValue.hasProperty("owner", is("myself")`

I've tried several way with no luck :

```
List<Object> o = response.extract().jsonPath().get("rows");
assertThat(o, hasItem(hasProperty("owner")));

assertThat(o.get(0),Matchers.hasProperty(TestConstants.DOC_OWNER));
```

But I get everytime

> Expected: a collection containing hasProperty("owner")
>        but: no "owner" in <{owner=myself, uid=927e2362-babb-47cc-8406-d618b0e15b89>, no "owner" in
>   <{owner=myself, uid=6d39c473-d0bd-496e-be86-40917aa3af79>

I've seen this [subjet](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/805) which explains that I may end up with an array of array. But I cannot see how to do it the simpliest way :
- Check that every item of my list has property **"owner"** and that its value is always **"myself"** (Filter used for the request)

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) as 'deep-equals' checks on nested JSON (or XML) is a core feature, and you don't need to depend on Hamcrest or anything else. You also have a `match each` keyword, designed for arrays:

```
* def data = { foo: [{ bar: 1, baz: 'a' }, { bar: 2, baz: 'b' }, { bar: 3, baz: 'c' }]}
* match each data.foo == { bar: '#number', baz: '#string' }
```

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. Seems really surprising this is not possible easily with hamcrest though